# Bind data-opacity attribute to scope variable

Tags: angularjs

There's a [jquery.minicolors](https://github.com/claviska/jquery-minicolors) pluggin, and there is a [angularified](http://kaihenzler.github.io/angular-minicolors/) version of this plugin that I wish use.

The usage is like so:

- On page open data for color picker (hex color and opacity) is retrieved from server.
- Then that values is used to "build" colorpicker (so that its color and opacity are equal to values received from server).
- Then user may click on picker and change color and opacity. Results **must** be reflected in corresponding $scope variables.

I have binded color hex value via `ng-model` and it works like a charm, but I have troubles with opacity. I have tried to use `ng-attr-` for `data-opacity` attribute, but when I change manually opacity, results are not "sent" back to scope variable..

```
<input minicolors="options" ng-model="thecolor" ng-attr-data-opacity="{{opacity}}">
```

To demonstrate this I have created a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EiA2PUkDw4DTnSGsCZPx?p=preview) with description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many attempts I have managed to modify source code to be able to two-way-bind opacity value to variable I desire. Here's a [modified plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PfUEk5?p=preview).

What I've added:

First, we modify the tag by passing in additional `watch-opacity="varname"` attribute to define what variable should hold the initial opacity value. This variable will also be changed when we change the opacity slider and viceversa - the opacity slider will change when new data is written into this variable (ex. data received from server).

```
<input minicolors="options" ng-model="thecolor" data-opacity="" watch-opacity="settings.somewhat.opacity">
```

Then we get the opacity value from our settings and ask minicolors to use it as opacity for now, or use 1.0 if the variable have no value yet.

```
var opacity = scope.$eval(attrs.watchOpacity) || "1.0";
element.minicolors('opacity', opacity);
```

And then we modify our `onchange` function so that our settings variable for opacity is being updated also when opacity is changed due to opacity slider change:

```
var settings = getSettings();
settings.change = function (hex, opacity) { // <- fix!
  scope.$apply(function () {
    ngModel.$setViewValue(hex);
    $parse(attrs.watchOpacity).assign(scope, opacity); // <- fix!
  });
};
```

That's it! This way we can define variable for each colorpicker that will hold opacity value and bind any opacity changes via slider to it.

Comment: nice workaround. The original minicolor-angular.js stills needs some work thou.

Comment: yes, but for now, for my needs, it works perfect. Later probably I should also make a pull request to original repo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the input field only binds to color part. If you add a ng-change to your input you will see that this is only fired if you change the color but not when opacity is changed.

You should move your code into a directive. Here you can use the "change" eventHandler from minicolors as describedin another question [Minicolors AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302020/using-jquery-minicolors-in-angular-js) and the [docs](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-minicolors/#events)

UPDATE

If you take a look at the code

http://kaihenzler.github.io/angular-minicolors/angular-minicolors.js

It seems like the change event is there but only binds the hex value.

```
    var settings = getSettings();
    settings.change = function (hex) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(hex);
      });
    };
```

I am guessing it should be.

```
    var settings = getSettings();
    settings.change = function (hex,opacity) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(hex);
      });
    };
```

But the opacity is not passed into any value. Seems like a bug in the directive. If you use a console.log(opacity) you can see the value change.

Update 2.

Simple fix for you

```
    settings.change = function (hex,opacity) {
      scope.opacity = opacity
      scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(hex);
      });
    };
```

Comment: so it isn't possible to make 2-way binding for opacity value?

Comment: sure 2-way binding would be possible. But you would have to tweak the minicolors-angular.js for that. I'll create a pull-request for it when I have some time. Meanwhile download the file and implement the fix I posted. This will work and update your controller $scope.opacity. I have forked your plunker example so that you can have a look at it [Example with fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/QQpXr0L9eB6LLl9pauwd?p=preview)

Comment: unfortunately having several color pickers at time will fail because they all will share the same $scope.opacity variable. Probably some additional ng attribute should be added passing to it variable to bind, and this variable should be updated each time data-opacity is changed..

Comment: correct. But you could create a controller within the directive. That way each colopicker has its own controller. As I said the minicolor-angular.js needs some work to support more options. Sorry if it isn't a perfect fix for you right now

Comment: I have found a solution and made a separate answer to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute watch:
**(edited)**

```
// Template
<input minicolors="options" ng-model="thecolor">

// Controller:
$("input[minicolors]").each(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        $scope.$watch(
            function() {
                return $self.attr("data-opacity");
            },
            function(opacity) {
                $scope.opacity[ $self.index() ] = opacity; 
            });
    });
```

Comment: as I understand if I have 10 polor pickers I would have to add 10 watches?

Comment: also, Rob, it will store all opacicies from all pickers in one variable.. probably it's better to go directive way as I mentioned in another answer..

Comment: Updated the answer again, to show a way how to store each opacity separately (in an array)...  This just an example but hopefully makes things clearer. And yes, maybe the directive makes more sense for your usecase...

Comment: array is a pretty bad solution, in my case, because I want to define which exactly variable will hold opacity. This variable should be 1 for each color picker I have, and this variable's value (initial value) is populated from server.